# XAML ContentControl child not stretching to fill ContentControl

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a really simple thing I'm trying to do but it's not working and I'm trying to understand what I'm missing.

So I have a `<ContentControl>` in a parent UI and am binding its `Content` property to a DependencyProperty on the controller:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="rightPanel">
```

(It is inside a Grid with the row height set to `*`.)

I am then instantiating a UserControl that contains a Grid (which should therefore stretch to fill the available space), but whenever I embed this into the UserControl it loses all "stretching" and starts shrinking down as if it were in a StackPanel.

```
<UserControl
    *namespace snip*>
    <Grid Background="LightGreen">
        <TextBlock Text="Oh happy days..."/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

…

```
var innerPage = new MyUserControl1(); // the above <UserControl>
this.rightPanel.Content = innerPage;
```

[image]

I can't figure out why this is happening. I've tried it with both `UserControl`s and `Page`s, no difference. What am I missing?

Comment: If you set a Background (just temporarily) on the Grid that contains the ContentControl, does it fill its own parent?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes it does, it only breaks down at the point of embedding.

Comment: Have you set the ContentControl's HorizontalContentAlignment / VerticalContentAlignment to Stretch ?

Comment: Yes I tried that too, it had no effect. Both on the parent ContentControl element and on the embedded page/user control.

Comment: Oh wait! I had tried `HorizontalAlignment` not `HorizontalContentAlignment`! That actually did the trick! Thank you so much. Feel free to post the answer and I'll give you the check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the ContentControl's HorizontalContentAlignment / VerticalContentAlignment to Stretch.

Comment: It is important to recognise the difference between `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` in this use case!